# Azure Api Management authtication to Azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

So I have read a lot lately around the API Management and web app authentication.
This one is probably the most best one to follow: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/protecting-apis-in-azure-api-management-using-oauth-2-0-client/ba-p/3054130

However, what I am trying to achieve is not only to be able to give access to INTERNAL AD workers, I also want to handle API/People outside of the organisation. I was hoping with the people who register (and are accepted by us) will be able to request a JWT via OAuth2.0. And then use their subscription key AND their token to enter the flow.
But I do not know how to set this up.
I saw something about authentication around the api management.
Any advise here how to accomplish the last piece for external people? (not making them an guest AD user (or Microsoft Entra ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to achieve is not only to be able to give access to INTERNAL AD workers, I also want to handle API/People outside of the organisation not making them an guest AD user (or Microsoft Entra)

To allow access to the Azure Ad Application all the users outside the organization, you must create application as  **multitenant**  by selecting "“*Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)*”

I created  **`APIMapp`**  and  **`APIMClientApp`**  as multitenant as below:

[image]

[image]

In  **`APIMapp`**  , exposed an API and make sure to add Authorized client applications:

*I added  **`APIMClientApp`**  Client ID as the client application*

[image]

In the APIM, updated the  **inbound policy**  as below:

```xml
<inbound>
<base  />
<validate-jwt  header-name="Authorization"  failed-validation-httpcode="401"  failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
<openid-config  url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration"  />
<required-claims>
<claim  name="aud"  match="any">
<value>APIMappClientID</value>
</claim>
</required-claims>
</validate-jwt>
</inbound>
```

Now to  **authorize another tenant user**, I used below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=APIMClientApp
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://APIMapp/user_impersonation
&state=12345
```

[image]

[image]

Generated the  **access token**  using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:APIMClientApp
scope:api://APIMapp/api.access
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
grant_type:authorization_code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I decoded the access token, scope is present:

[image]

- Using the above access token another tenant user can call the APIM.
- If you want to authorize other tenant Azure AD users only then create application by selecting “*Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant)*”
- And make use of  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/`

**Reference:**

[Client application configuration (MSAL) - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#authority)

Comment: Thnx for the Great explanation! Is there also a way to limit the users to those who have registered in APIM? I am in doubt what the best practice is for security for people outside the organization. Do I have to create a secret for each of them? Or leave them as one external api? I was hoping to setup a oauth2 flow per registered user in APIM or something... your thoughts?

Comment: Or is that actually the combination of subscription key and the oauth flow? In that particular case i do not have to create additional resources. Then adding a secret to the "client app" would be suffice. Handing it over the people outside of the organisation + subscriptionkey would cover it then i gues.. ? Then the clients can obtain a token via client_cedentials, and use that as authentication... ? thoughts?